# How to retrieve 1M documents with elasticsearch in Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

How I can get 100000 registers in elasticsearch from python? MatchAll query only retrieve 10000.

Comment: How are you retrieving your documents ? Can you add some code ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like it's been pointed out, I'd use the Scan API to do that.

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

ES_HOST = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 9200
}
ES_INDEX = "index_name"
ES_TYPE = "type_name"

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[ES_HOST], )

results_gen = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
    es,
    query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
    index=ES_INDEX,
    doc_type=ES_TYPE
)

results = list(results_gen)
```

You ought also reading about the scan helper in elasticsearch python DSL         http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan.

Ref. [Helpers](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html).

Comment: how I can read the data then of this? I can store it in a variable?

Comment: if it fits, yes. You can assign it to a result variable

Comment: This is what I do `data=elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
    es,
    query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
    index="sku_index",
    doc_type="part"
 )` but it returns `<generator object scan at 0x02C39260>`

Comment: I don't have an env to test it now. I'll get back to your later when I do.

Comment: Is it posbible I need a scroll parameter?

Comment: can you post the result of `scroll_size = results['hits']['total']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134502/discussion-between-joan-triay-and-eliasah).

Comment: I'm sorry but not works...

Comment: I know this is an old question but your import statement should really be `import elasticsearch.helpers`.

Comment: @JoanTriay list(data) converts a generator to a list

Answer (score 1):

It is forbidden to have sum of "size" and "offset" more than 10000.

You need to use `scan` api. There is neat handy helper for this over there http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan