# Elasticsearch helper returns generator class, need dictionary

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using the [scan API](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan) to query elasticsearch and return an unlimited number of results (as opposed to the 10k limit). This returns a generator object, which I then need to turn into a dictionary (because the results will then be turned into a pandas data frame).

I attempted `logs = {c.name:c.value for c in logs}` but it returned an empty list. I know the results themselves came back because they printed when I attempted `for i in logs: \\ print(i)`. How can I turn my results into a dictionary?

**Code**

```
import elasticsearch.helpers
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, TransportError, RequestsHttpConnection

def check_query(query, index):
    ES_user = environ.get('ES_USER')
    ES_pw = environ.get('ES_PW')
    ES_cluster = environ.get('ES_CLUSTER')

    es = Elasticsearch([ES_cluster],
                       connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
                       http_auth=(ES_user, ES_pw),
                       use_ssl=True, verify_certs=False)

    try:
        logs = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es, query=query, index=index)
        logs = {c.name:c.value for c in logs} # returns empty list
    except Exception as e:
        logs = 'Please contact the application supporter and provide them the information below! \n'
        logs += 'Error: ' + str(e) + '\n'
        logs += 'Query: ' + query
    return logs
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `logs = {c.name:c.value for c in logs}` is not raising `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'`, can you please provide the full error message, including the stack trace?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added to original question

Comment: So, it's not really the dict-comprehension perse that's raising that error, it's simply the act of iterating over the result. Are you sure you passed the correct argument types? it seems like it was expecting a `dict` somewhere and you provided a `str`, for the `query` argument from what I can gather. How are you calling this?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga pretty sure, though I'm new to this helper; I wrote based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961245/how-to-retrieve-1m-documents-with-elasticsearch-in-python) SO question

Comment: So what exactly are you passing for the query?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just a basic `{"query": {"match_all": {}}}` which I know is valid because it returned results when I did `logs = es.search(index=index, body=query, size=10000)`.

Comment: Can you simpy iterate over the result? Again, the problem isn't that it's a generator, it's that something is wrong with the query.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just realized I was wrapping the query in a string. However, still having an issue converting to dictionary. Edited question.

Comment: Did you iterate over it before trying to convert it to a dict?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was able to put it into a list

Comment: And then you tried the dict comprehension? Because that would mean you're exhausting the iterator. Look, you really need to provide *exactly* what you're doing.